# How to use bootstrap css in Maatwebsite export PDF?

Tags: css, pdf, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite export library in Laravel 5.1, I want to generate Invoice (PDF) , can anybody please let me know how to use bootstrap css with it?
I tried this :

```
$usheet = 'view_invoice'; 
Excel::create($usheet.'_'.time(), function($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
        global $export_data;
        $sheet->setOrientation('test');
        $dompdf->set_base_path('bootstrap.min.css');
        $sheet->loadView("administrator.detail/exportInvoiceDetail",$export_data);
    });
})->export('pdf');`
```

but it is not working, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!